# ExtJS 4.2.1 - border layout with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, extjs4.2

i need a layout something like this:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/21i

I need the west filter panel to be collapsable and my content panel has a dynamic height.

A possibility could also be that the panel with the boarder layout has a full height and the overflow is just scrollable...

Though i dont get a valid border layout without setting a total height to my panel.

Please help

**UPDATE**

A nice workaround would be appreciated too...

**EDIT**

a new fiddler with dynamic generated content

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty workaround is to let render the body of the dynamic panel and adjust the height of your main container accordingly. You'll need to account for anything that adds height to the center panel's body.

For example, with your code, you can add a listener like this to your border layout container:

```
listeners: {
    delay: 1,
    afterrender: function() {
        this.setHeight(
            this.down('[region=center]').body.getHeight()
            + this.getHeader().getHeight()
            // also account for borders, margins, etc. if needed
        );
    }
}
```

See your [updated fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/21u).

**Update**  Toward a more robust solution

As I said in the comment, Ext4 makes it quite easy to make a panel collapsible with 'hbox' layout, and probably most other kinds.

Here's a good starter ([fiddled there](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/225)):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.widget('viewport', {
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
            ,align: 'stretch'
        }
        ,items: [{
            title: 'left'
            ,width: 150
            ,resizable: true
            ,resizeHandles: 'e'
            ,style: {
                borderRight: '2px solid #157FCC'
            }
            ,collapsible: true
            ,collapseDirection: 'left'
            ,defaultType: 'button'
            ,layout: {
                type: 'vbox'
                ,align: 'stretch'
            }
            ,items: [{
                text: "Foo"
            },{
                text: "Bar"
            },{
                text: "Baz"
            }]
        },{
            title: 'center'
            ,flex: 1
            ,autoScroll: true
            ,tbar: [{
                text: "Add content"
                ,handler: function() {
                    this.up('panel').add({
                        html: "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>"
                    })
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: another idea which i got in my head is using column layout or hbox layout and write a plugin for my filterpanel to collapse it to the right.. which of the two options do you like more? how would you decide?

Comment: your solution doesnt completely fit my requirements because i do generate /alter the content on the fly.. and i am collapsing/expanding panels in my center panel... here a [new Fiddler](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/221) when you press the button you will see my issue

Comment: Yes, you will have to recalculate the size each time you change the content, and each time the window or main container is resized. An additional issue you will encounter is that, with long dynamic content, your left tool panel will be scrolled out of view... All in all, I would not use border layout. As it turns out, Ext4 provides collapsible and resizable behaviour out of the box for every component, making it quite easy to do what you want with an hbox layout. I'm updating my answer with this solution.

Comment: thanks very much - wasnt aware of collapseDirection >.< feeling so newb :D

Comment: or, dear reader, if you prefer the short answer, see below ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align : 'stretch',
            pack  : 'start'
        }
```

in a container ( window, panel, ..)
and:

```
Flex: 1
```

in a component within, like a grid.

Works pretty good, in my experience.  ( as suggested in the layout examples from the Sencha site and Forum remarks )

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'border' layout and replace it with

```
layout: {
  type: 'hbox',
  pack: 'start',
  align: 'stretch'
},
```

Now you can remove the heights and it will fit dynamically